# Como obter arquivo no notes(csv) utilizando javascript, abri-lo e alocar as linhas do mesmo em variaveis?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando fazer o  upload de um arquivo CSV utilizando do Notes IBM.

Tenho a função que faz o upload do arquivo funcionando.

O problema é abri-lo utilizando javascript dentro do Notes e fazer a leitura do arquivo em CSV.

Tentei utilizar o comando FOpen disponível no JavaScript, porém a função que armazena o arquivo no servidor em JavaScript não tem métodos de acesso incluídas.

Como retornar o conteúdo do arquivo do FileUpload?